# Array index of smallest number greater than a given number in a sorted array using C

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search-tree

Need to find the index of a number, that may or may not be present in the array. I tried the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *lhs, const void *rhs){
    return ( *(long long*)lhs - *(long long*)rhs );
}
int main(){
    int size = 9;
    long long a[] = {16426799,16850699,17802287,18007499,18690047,18870191,18870191,19142027,19783871};

    long long x = 17802287;
    long long *p  = (long long *)bsearch(&x, a, size, sizeof(long long), cmp);

    if (p != NULL)
        printf("%lld\n", p - a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works if the number, in this case 17802287 is present in the array `a`, but fails if the number is not present in `a`, e.g. doesn't give any output for `x=18802288`, I would like to get the index `i=5` in that case 5th element onwards the elements are greater than 18802288.

Also the actual array size will have number of elements more than 4 million, would the same code work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no such function in standard C, but making a binary search function with the extra functionality you want should not be very hard. Making your own function you could also add an argument that gets set to non-zero if an exact match was found, and zero if not, making it easy for the caller to decide what to do with the result.

Comment: Hmm, I was trying to port some python code to C, got stuck here. My C knowledge is not good enough to make an efficient search function.

Comment: [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is (IMO) one of the easiest search algorithms. Experiment a little, try to make your own binary search function, just a simple one that returns an exact match (like `bsearch`), then you can work on tweaking it to fit your requirements. But be careful for corner cases though, your requirements might give you trouble if the value you search for is larger than the last element in the array.

Comment: Found the source of `bisect_left` in python, so ported that to C. Works nicely. No problem of corner cases for me, as the number would be deep inside the middle of the array.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for `bsearch`:

> The bsearch() function returns a pointer to a matching  member  of 
>   the array,  or  NULL  if no match is found.  If there are multiple
>   elements that match the key, the element returned is unspecified.

So the function will return NULL if the element in question is not found.  If you want to find the first element greater than or equal to the number in question, you'll need to roll your own function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution can be:

```
int i, outcome = -1;
for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    if( x == a[i] )
    {
        outcome = i;
        break;
    }
}

printf("%d\n", outcome);
```

Comment: "Also the actual array size will have number of elements more than 4 million" That's probably not a viable solution. Like the original solution, this code will only work if `x` is present in the array..

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that does approximately this:

```
bsearch_geq (number array low high)

   if low is equal to high return high

   let halfway be average of low and high

   if array[halfway] is equal to number then return halfway
   if array[halfway] is greater than number then
      return result of "bsearch_geq number array low halfway"
   else
      return result of "bsearch_geq number array halfway high"
```

That'll get you 99% of the way, I think, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out the corner cases. The main one I can see is what happens when you get down to just two numbers because the naive "average" may cause infinite recursion.

If you can have multiple occurrences of the *same* number in the array then you'll need to drop the `if array[halfway] is equal]" line`.

You should ensure your solution uses [tail-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) for efficiency, but it's not too critical as 4m data-entries only amounts to about 15 recursive calls.